# How to use Google Charts with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, webforms, google-visualization

I am a new developer and I am trying to use Google Charts in my simple test ASP.NET application. I was able to create a user control and C# class for each Google Chart Type by following one of the open-source projects about using Google Charts in ASP.NET.

I am struggling right now in creating an object array in order to bind it to the Google Chart control. 
Basically, the C# code of the object array should look like the following:

```
List<object[]> _list = new List<object[]>();
_list.Add(new object[] { "Country", "Popularity" });
_list.Add(new object[] { "India", 200 });
_list.Add(new object[] { "United States", 0 });
_list.Add(new object[] { "Brazil", 400 });
_list.Add(new object[] { "Canada", 500 });
_list.Add(new object[] { "France", 600 });
_list.Add(new object[] { "RU", 700 });

// Column Chart
ColumnOption columnOption = new ColumnOption();
columnOption.legend = new Legend("top");
GoogleChartColumn.ColumnData = new ColumnParam(_list, columnOption);
```

And I was able to retrieve the data using Entity Framework and store them in object as follows:

```
var sqlQuery = @"SELECT T_Category.Title AS Category, COUNT(T_Tweet.Id) AS TweetCounts
                                FROM T_Category INNER JOIN 
                                    T_Tweet ON T_Category.Id = T_Tweet.CategoryId
                                GROUP BY T_Category.Title";
            var catTweets = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<TweetCategoryModel>(sqlQuery).ToList();


            //*******************************************
            var chartData = new object[catTweets.Count + 1];
            chartData[0] = new object[]{
                "Category",
                "Number of Tweets",
            };

            int j = 0;
            foreach (var i in catTweets)
            {
                j++;
                chartData[j] = new object[] { i.Category.ToString(), i.TweetCounts };
            }
```

I am struggling now in how to add the `chartData` object to the object array `_list` in order to construct the Google Chart

**Could you please tell me how I can do that?**

UPDATE:
Here's a snapshot of the error I am getting right now after adding `chartData` array to the array of objects `_list` :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq00z.png)

Answer (score 0):

> I am struggling now in how to add the chartData object to the object array _list in order to construct the Google Chart

The `_list` variable is a list of an array of `object`. The `chartData` variable is an array of `object`. To add it, you simply do this:

```
_list.Add(chartData);
```

Now I am not sure if that will make your whole application work but your question is clearly asking how to add `chartData` to `_list` and that is how.

Comment: thanks for your great help. As mentioned in the first part of the code in my question, this code could be used from the code-behind to add data to Google Chart. I don't need to have a web method. All what I need right now is a way to convert the array of data to object array in order to bind it to the chart.

Comment: You can create an array of anything and it will work for an array of data.

Comment: I am struggling now with that thing as shown in the second part of my question. Could you please help me with that thing?

Comment: @TechLover I have changed my answer to show how to add `chartData` to `_list`.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I already did that as mentioned in my question above. Could you please have a look at my question as I just updated it with a snapshot of the error I am getting from Google Visualization Engine?